# Method as an argument of base class constructor in subclass constructor

Tags: c++, inheritance, constructor

```
    class Base {
        Base (string, string);
    };

    class A : private Base {
        A (int, int);
    };
```

Is it allowed to use a class A's method in A's constructor as an argument of Base's constructor?
I mean:

```
    A::A (int augend, int addend)
                  : Base(int_to_binary_string(6),int_to_binary_string(5)),
                    augend(augend), addend(addend)
    {

    }
```

**int_to_binary_string()** is A's method. I always thought that such a construction is not allowed, couse at first A_parent must be build, so A's methods do not exist yet.

Comment: Why is `int_to_binary_string` a member of `A` in the first place?

Comment: yes you can do it only if the function is NOT virtual.

Comment: @user657267 A is a wrapper, I want to converse int to string which cointens binary number.

Comment: @Thomas thank you, it works

Comment: @JohnKokonesko A wrapper for what? Also it sounds like you're reimplementing [`std::bitset`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/bitset).

Comment: @JohnKokonesko  anyway, you must make sure that the function that you call in ctor never use the data which hasnt been initialized. In your example,  if `int_to_binary_string` doesn't use the data of A or of A_parent, then it's OK. Go to check the duplicated question.